# After file type validation using JS for an HTML Form, control should stay on the same page if invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html `form` where for file types I want only pdf, docx and doc files. I am successfully able to validate, but on click of OK button, I do not want to post the form if it is invalid. Currently, it is going to connection.php. It should only go to connection.php when I have passed the validation successfully.

```
<form method="POST" action="connection.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="function()">
<input type="text" id="name" name="bookname" placeholder="Book Name" required/>
<textarea cols="25" rows="4" name="bookdesc" placeholder="Book Description" required></textarea>
<input type="text" id="password" name="bookauthor" placeholder="Book Author"/ required>
<input type="file" name="bookfile" id="bookfile" required/>
</form>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type=file]').change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        var regex = new RegExp("(.*?)\.(docx|doc|pdf)$");
         if(!(regex.test(val))) {
        $(this).val('');
        alert('Please select correct file format');
        } }); });
    </script>
```

Comment: If you need to validate the file content you should do so on the server side. You can meet the 'stay on the same page if invalid' requirement using Ajax. The file name extension does not ensure the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onsubmit` event:

```
<form method="POST" action="connection.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate()">
<input type="text" id="name" name="bookname" placeholder="Book Name" required/>
<textarea cols="25" rows="4" name="bookdesc" placeholder="Book Description" required></textarea>
<input type="text" id="password" name="bookauthor" placeholder="Book Author"/ required>
<input type="file" name="bookfile" id="bookfile" required/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload book">
</form>
<script>
    function validate() {
    var val = document.getElementById('bookfile').value.toLowerCase();
    var regex = new RegExp("(.*?)\.(docx|doc|pdf)$");
        if(!(regex.test(val))) {
            document.getElementById('bookfile').value = '';
            alert('Please select correct file format');
            return false;    
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, because: 1) the form was missing a submit button, 2) the javascript code was relying on the jQuery library - I have removed the dependency.

Comment: I was able to achieve the same using onsubmit="return validate(this)". Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" action="connection.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">
<input type="text" id="name" name="bookname" placeholder="Book Name" required/>
<textarea cols="25" rows="4" name="bookdesc" placeholder="Book Description" required></textarea>
<input type="text" id="password" name="bookauthor" placeholder="Book Author"/ required>
<input type="file" name="bookfile" id="bookfile" required/>
</form>
    <script>
        var isValid = false;
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type=file]').change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        var regex = new RegExp("(.*?)\.(docx|doc|pdf)$");
        isValid = !!(regex.test(val));
         if(!isValid) {
        $(this).val('');
        alert('Please select correct file format');
        } }); });
        $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
            if (!isValid) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I have added an `id` to your `form`. Using this `id` as a selector I have created a `submit` handler for the `form`. This handler checks whether `isValid` is `false` and if so, calls `e.preventDefault()`, which prevents the `form` from submitting. If `isValid` was `true`, then `e.preventDefault()` will not be called, therefore the `form` submits. `isValid` is initialized with `false` and is evaluated on `input[type=file]` `change`.

Comment: When I am using this, I am not getting any error message when I Upload a jpeg file and click on Submit. It directly goes to connection.php

Comment: @Alapan did you define an id for your form tag?